# How do i create a list of monsters based on already created objects, that the player can interact with

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming, and i'm trying to make a little text based rpg, i've learned lots so far from doing it, and i'm just trying to learn more :)

I have some objects(possible monsters to add to a battle), based on a class above for NPC's, assigned to some variables...

```
goblin = Monsters('Goblin', 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'melee', 1, 0, 0, 1) 

bear = Monsters('Bear', 15, 15, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 'melee', 2, 0, 0, 2) 

boar = Monsters('Boar', 10, 10, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'melee', 1, 0, 0, 1) 

wolf = Monsters('Wolf', 15, 15, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 'melee', 2, 0, 0, 2) 

kobold = Monsters('Kobold', 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'caster', 1, 0, 0, 3) 

sprite = Monsters('Sprite', 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 2, 'support', 2, 0, 0, 3)
```

I take these and add them to a list

```
easyBattleMonsters = [goblin, bear, boar, wolf, kobold, sprite]
```

I have a function, that is probably awful, but I'm new so i made it this way i guess, that will add up to 5 monsters in a battle to fight, based on players level

```
def easyBattle():

    if playerCharacter.level < 6:

        easyBattle.easyMobOne = []

        easyMobLevel = []

        easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)

        easyBattle.easyMonsterOne = random.choice(easyBattleMonsters)

        easyBattle.easyMobOne.append(easyBattle.easyMonsterOne.name)

        easyMobLevel.append(easyBattle.easyMonsterOne.level)

        easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)

        if easyMobLevelSum < playerCharacter.level:

            easyMonsterTwo = random.choice(easyBattleMonsters)

            easyBattle.easyMobOne.append(easyMonsterTwo.name)

            easyMobLevel.append(easyMonsterTwo.level)

            easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)

            if easyMobLevelSum < playerCharacter.level:

                easyMonsterThree = random.choice(easyBattleMonsters)

                easyBattle.easyMobOne.append(easyMonsterThree.name)

                easyMobLevel.append(easyMonsterThree.level)

                easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)

                if easyMobLevelSum < playerCharacter.level:

                    easyMonsterFour = random.choice(easyBattleMonsters)

                    easyBattle.easyMobOne.append(easyMonsterFour.name)

                    easyMobLevel.append(easyMonsterFour.level)

                    easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)

                    if easyMobLevelSum < playerCharacter.level:

                        easyMonsterFive = random.choice(easyBattleMonsters)

                        easyBattle.easyMobOne.append(easyMonsterFive.name)

                        easyMobLevel.append(easyMonsterFive.level)

                        easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel) 

        easyMobLevelSum = sum(easyMobLevel)
```

i have a feeling my above code is what i need to change, but not sure what i should do, i would like to be able to instantiate like, a temporary list of objects based on what i added to easyBattle.easyMobOne. something like, when it imports a wolf, to become the new 'monster1' with the name from that object, and they can attack it and kill it, and it won't affect the original object of wolf. then, when they're done with that fight it just loses the variables they were fighting, and they could start up another fight and have new monsters. i just want to be able to have them have multiple choices to attack, and they all have their own seperate stats, and not sure the best way to do that currently

Comment: You're kind of mixing classes and instances here. You may want to rethink things so e.g. `Goblin` is a subclass of `Monster`, so instantiating, say, 200 goblins becomes easier.

Comment: @AKX not necessarily - it indeed makes sense if there are behavioral differences between monsters types (and even then it could be solved with the strategy pattern), but "simplifying" monsters instanciation can be done with just factory functions. (NB: ok, nitpicking...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment – you might want to model things so there's a base class for all monsters, and the various sorts of monsters subclasses thereof, and single monsters (Goblin 1, Goblin 2, ...) are instances of those classes. Here's a moderately simple implementation of that (moderately simple as I couldn't resist adding a name generator...).

Hope this sheds some light on things!

```
import random


# A helper to generate a random integer from a 2-tuple.
# Saves some typing below.
def _rand_range(minmax):
    return random.randint(minmax[0], minmax[1])


class Monster:
    # Class-level variables to govern how monsters are instantiated.
    hp_range = (0, 0)
    str_range = (0, 0)
    dex_range = (0, 0)
    name_characters = ""
    name_length_range = (0, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        # Use the class-level variables to set instance variables for
        # each individual monster.
        self.hp = _rand_range(self.hp_range)
        self.str = _rand_range(self.str_range)
        self.dex = _rand_range(self.dex_range)
        # If the name generator returns a falsy value (such as an empty string),
        # substitute Anonymous for this individual's name.
        self.name = self.generate_name() or "Anonymous"

    def generate_name(self):
        # This could be overridden in a subclass (I'm sure elves would have much more graceful
        # names than just random letters one after the other).

        name_length = _rand_range(self.name_length_range)
        # Pick `name_length` random letters from `name_characters` and join them.
        return "".join(random.choice(self.name_characters) for x in range(name_length)).title()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} named {self.name} ({self.hp} HP, {self.str} STR, {self.dex} DEX)"


class Goblin(Monster):
    """
    A relatively weak monster type with high dexterity.
    """

    hp_range = (10, 15)
    str_range = (1, 3)
    dex_range = (3, 5)
    name_characters = "ppiao"
    name_length_range = (3, 7)


class Wolf(Monster):
    """
    A sturdy wolf-type thing that's kind of slow, but packs a punch.
    Would really just like to be scratched.
    """

    hp_range = (15, 25)
    str_range = (3, 5)
    dex_range = (1, 2)
    name_characters = "rwegrhr"
    name_length_range = (2, 9)


def generate_battle(monster_classes, battle_total_hp):
    # Instantiate a list to hold the monster instances.
    monsters = []
    # Compute the sum of the HPs of all monsters in this battle so far;
    # so long as that number is less than the requested total HP, keep
    # adding new monsters to the fray.  This will not guarantee that the
    # total HP of the battle is as prescribed, since the last monster generated
    # may be too powerful, but it's in the ballpark.
    while sum((m.hp for m in monsters), 0) < battle_total_hp:
        # Pick a monster class at random...
        monster_cls = random.choice(monster_classes)
        # Instantiate the monster, just as if you'd done `w = Wolf()`, etc.
        monster = monster_cls()
        # Add it to the list.
        monsters.append(monster)
    return monsters


# Generate a battle of about 100 HP using goblins and wolves.
# As a neat trick, to make goblins twice as likely to appear as wolves,
# simply repeat Goblin: [Goblin, Goblin, Wolf]
battle = generate_battle([Goblin, Wolf], battle_total_hp=100)

print("A battle begins!")
for monster in battle:
    print(monster)
```

Running this, you'll see something like

```
A battle begins!
Wolf named Eergrwheh (21 HP, 4 STR, 1 DEX)
Goblin named Ppi (13 HP, 2 STR, 5 DEX)
Goblin named Ipa (12 HP, 3 STR, 4 DEX)
Goblin named Ppiip (11 HP, 3 STR, 4 DEX)
Wolf named Ergrrrh (21 HP, 5 STR, 2 DEX)
Goblin named App (10 HP, 3 STR, 4 DEX)
Goblin named Ppappia (10 HP, 1 STR, 3 DEX)
Goblin named Apopi (13 HP, 1 STR, 3 DEX)
```